# 500(Internal Server Error): Forge deployed on Azure

Tags: azure, autodesk-forge

I am new to this topic. I have deployed my app to Azure (following the tutorial from Autodesk). When I try to press to the login to BIM360 is return an error 500 (internal Server Error). I have changed the FORGE_CALLBACK_URL = "htttp://*forgeSample1234*.azurewebsite.net/api/forge/callback/oauth"
The code has no problem when in localhost.

Does anyone has the same problem?

Comment: `http` instead of `htttp` ? Or it's just a typo writing this question ?

Comment: Hi it was a typo writing it. the problem was to retreive the app settings. I have used Envirnment.GetEnvironmentVariable and now is working correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please note that when updating the callback URL, you actually have to change it in two places:

- in your code (that's typically the `FORGE_CALLBACK_URL`)
- in your Forge app page in https://forge.autodesk.com/myapps

And of course, the URL has to match exactly in both places.

Also, it looks like there might be a typo in your URL: you say `htttp` instead of `http`, and I'm also wondering if you shouldn't be using `https`?

Comment: Thanks for for your support. I have managed to deploy succesfully. I was giving me again error 500 about the 3legged autethication, about invalid cleintId. I had registered client id, secret id and url in the azure platform in the app settings. Still it was returning the error. In the end in the code I change in the controller "OAuthController.cs" theGetAppSetting using Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable() and now is working. Is it an acceptable solution?
     Thanks